# @Html.ActionLink and @Html.DisplayFor at the same time (not right, but it describes what I want to do)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, actionlink

I have the following table located in a view within a controller named Student (/Student/Details/1):

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.Enrollments)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Course.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Grade)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

I would like to make each table definition into a link that takes me to a view within a controller named Course (/Course/Details/1).

I have tried things along the lines of:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Course.Title, "Details", "Course"))
```

in place of

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Course.Title)
```

Which does not compile.  How would I appropriately display my model's title along with a link to the details of the referenced title?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If I understand right your question, you want a link with the text of the course.

This should work:

```
  @Html.ActionLink(item.Course.Title, "Details", "Course")
```

If you want to pass the ID of the course to the controller (assuming your routing rules are set correctly and the Id is something like: item.Course.Id)

```
  @Html.ActionLink(item.Course.Title, "Details", "Course", new { Id = item.Course.Id }, null /* html attributes */)
```

If you need to use the UIHint attribute on the property, to add extra formatting, you can use this

```
  <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Course", new { Id=item.Course.Id})">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Course.Title)</a>
```

Comment: I believe the second bit of code is exactly what I needed.  Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I'm having a bit of trouble.  I used this code:
@Html.ActionLink(item.Course.Title, "Details", "Course", new { id= item.Course.CourseID })
but every link generated links specifically to this:
/Student/Details/2?Length=6
Why would this happen?  I do not know where the "?Length=6" comes from, nor why it is still going through my /Student controller instead of my /Course controller.

Comment: Wait, I think I see my mistake.  Will reply shortly.

Comment: I wrote the code "on the fly". I missed the null for the HtmlAttributes. Edited the answer.

Comment: I fixed it by using: @Html.ActionLink(item.Course.Title, "Details", "Course", new { id= item.Course.CourseID }, "a")  I had added the "a" at the end, and it forced it to use the proper controller name of "Course" - without the "a" it was using a different overload that did not allow the course to be assigned.  I could not get it to link properly without the "a".  Any tips on solving that bit of weirdness?  (nothing appears functionally wrong, just a bit odd - I have no idea what the "a" is actually doing")

Comment: As stated in my previous comment llok at the corrected line of code. That should do it. @Html.ActionLink(item.Course.Title, "Details", "Course", new { Id = item.Course.Id }, null /* html attributes */)

Comment: Actually, `DisplayFor` can return text that is [quite different](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16738096/11683) from just the property value. It would be better to use [`DisplayTextFor`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3473624/11683) or `ValueFor` to get the text for the link.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot an `)` after `Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Course.Title`.

Maybe try adding a `.ToString()` to it might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
// you want to use link with the displaying a course. you can use.

<a href = "@url.action("Details","course",new {Id = item.Course.Id}
@html.displayfor(m => m.Course.Title)</a>

// second approach

 @Html.ActionLink(item.Course.Title, "Details", "Course", new { Id = item.Course.Id })
```

Comment: If you want to pass the ID of the course to the controller (assuming your routing rules are set correctly and the Id is something like: item.Course.Id)