# What is the difference between @Html.ValueFor(x=>x.PropertyName) and @Model.PropertyName

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
@Html.ValueFor(x=>x.PropertyName) 
@Model.PropertyName
```

It seems like these two Razor commands do the exact same thing. Is there any special circumstance or benefit of using one over the other?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`ValueFor` will invoke the template that exists for rendering the type that the property has. By default this template may be as simple as `ToString()`, but you can define anything as the template.

`@Model.PropertyName` will simply present the value as string.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.valueextensions.valuefor(v=vs.108).aspx) for `ValueFor` : "Provides a mechanism to create custom HTML markup compatible with the ASP.NET MVC model binders and templates."

Answer (score 33):

`@Html.ValueFor(x => x.PropertyName)` invokes a lot a code and reflection under the hood.
It will allow you to customize the way the value is presented, and then have a consistent format across your whole site.
For example, if your property is decorated with `DisplayFormatAttribute`.

`@Model.PropertyName` is literally getting the value of the property directly, calling ToString() on it, and HTML escaping the result.  No other formatting will take place.

To illustrate, you might see this:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:C}")]
public decimal PropertyName = 1234.56;

@Html.ValueFor(x => x.PropertyName)  =>  "£1,234.56"
@Model.PropertyName                  =>  "1234.56"
```

Comment: That's a great example. Thank you!