# Difference between DisplayFor and ValueFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view-helpers

I'm wondering what the difference is between `ValueFor`, which I didn't know until recently, and `DisplayFor`, which I've been using for displaying values.

I set up a test project in which I created a Model with 2 properties:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Montant")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}")]
    public Decimal Amount
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Date d'achat")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Here's the result I'm getting:

```
TestModel model = new TestModel
{
    Amount = 1234.333M,
    Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-10)
};

@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Amout)   => "1 234,33 €"
@Html.ValueFor(x => x.Amount)    => "1234,333"

@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Date)    => "23/03/2014"
@Html.ValueFor(x => x.Date)      => "23/03/2014 00:00:00"
```

From what I see, there's no advantage of using `ValueFor` instead of `@Model.PropertyName`

While looking for answers, I stumbled on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738010/what-is-the-difference-between-html-valueforx-x-propertyname-and-model-prop/) where the most upvoted answer, while not voted best answer, gives different results than mine.

Anyone knows why we get different results and what is the **real** use of `ValueFor`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First I've heard of `ValueFor` as well....however, looking at the [source](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/ValueExtensions.cs) it would appear that `ValueFor` does a simple render <strike>using only the metadata against the model</strike> ignoring any associated templates (built-in or custom).

---

Further digging shows that in actual fact, the result of `ValueFor` is the equivalent to calling `String.Format` or `Convert.ToString` using the current culture depending on whether you provide a custom format

```
@Html.ValueFor(x => x.Amount) = Convert.ToString(x.Amount, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
@Html.ValueFor(x => x.Amount, "0.00") = String.Format(x.Amount, "0.00", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Comment: How would you explain that the metadata (`DataType` and `DisplayFormat`) is not used **at all** when I use `ValueFor` then?

Comment: @mickaeld although the source indicates it *should* be using the metadata - in actual fact it doesn't. If you follow the source path it calls `HtmlHelper.FormatValue` which internally calls `ViewDataDictionary.FormatValueInternal` which in turn just calls `Convert.ToString` or `String.Format` depending on whether you have supplied a custom format parameter or not. I have revised my answer

Comment: @mickaeld: You should only use ValueFor if you are building your own HTML helper extensions.

Comment: @JakobChristensen I'm not sure the method would have been exposed as an extension method if it was meant to be used **only** in custom HTML helper methods. Looks like it's just useful if you want to easily apply formatting when displaying a raw value.